# The eigenvalue of Laplace problem on a domain with a line removed

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-functions

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^2$ be given such that $\Omega$ is open bounded with nice boundary. Let $\Gamma$ be a finite segment in $\Omega$. We also define $\Omega_1:=\Omega\setminus \Gamma$.

Clearly we have $\Omega_1\subset \Omega$.

Now, let $\lambda$ be the smallest eigenvalue of operator $-\Delta$ in $\Omega$ and $\lambda_1$ be the smallest eigenvalue of operator $-\Delta$ in $\Omega_1$.

We all use Neumann boundary condition.

My question: do we necessarily have $\lambda_1\geq\lambda$?

---

I know in generally we should. Say, if $\Omega_1$ is a small cube and $\Omega$ is a bigger cube, then if $u_1$ is an eigenfunction in $\Omega_1$, then $u_1$ is also an eigenfunction in $\Omega$. But this does not hold in my case.

Comment: Are you assuming Dirichlet condition?

Comment: @ArcticChar sorry I am using Neman condition

Comment: @ArcticChar ah wrong spelling. I'm using my phone but I think you understand what I mean :)